# How can I extract text using regex on a string that containts both English and Hebrew?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, hebrew

I have strings in the following format and am trying to extract in python the word(s) before the file extension but before the word `שנה`. In the first example I want the word `בראשית` and in the second `חיי שרה`

`1. בראשית שנה ה_ - שפת התורה.pdf`

`5. חיי שרה שנה ה_ - כתיבת כתובה.pdf`

I've tried a few regexs, including
`regex = '\d\..+שנה (. +)\.pdf` but can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
r'\d.\s(.*)\sשנה.*.pdf'
```

Please see the full code snippet below:

```
import re

match_object = re.match(r'\d.\s(.*)\sשנה.*.pdf', '1. בראשית שנה ה_ - שפת התורה.pdf')
print(match_object.groups()[0])
# prints בראשית
match_object = re.match(r'\d.\s(.*)\sשנה.*.pdf', '5. חיי שרה שנה ה_ - כתיבת כתובה.pdf')
print(match_object.groups()[0])
# prints חיי שרה
```